# camera2: Green preview with samsung s6/s7

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am making my custom camera app based on [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample and modified it in order to use manual setting.

When the `CONTROL_AWB_MODE` is set to `CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO`, the preview is fine. But It becomes green after `CONTROL_MODE` , `CONTROL_AWB_MODE` are set to `CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF` and `CONTROL_AWB_LOCK` is set to `true` in Samsung s6/s7 as following image.

[image]

Comment: then you must to set CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO. Because when you set this.Your Device [S6 & S7] will takes an AWB Mode Automatically.

Comment: and some samsung device can not set AWB mode always on it. Like Always On or OFF.thats why you must to set AUTO Mode

Comment: setting it AWB auto and then locking it is recommended in here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AWB_LOCK

Comment: I am taking multiple photos, and in order to stitch them, all of the photos should have same AWB, exposure time, iso, focus distance,...

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Same problem in a Huawei P20 Lite, with same greenish colors, so I'm guessing is not a vendor specific problem.

Comment: @PerracoLabs It was very headache to take care of all android devices. I used samsung sdk, it solves a lot of issues

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following line of code resolved this issue for me.

mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_LOCK, true);